# Azure DevOps Api 203 error with bearer token

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to call a build pipeline from a function app. I've managed to do it with Powershell, but when using python, azure DevOps keeps giving me a 203 response and the pipeline is never run.
it successfully gets a token, but doesn't look like azure DevOps accepts it.

```
    import datetime
    import logging
    import azure.functions as func
    import os
    import requests
    import json

    app = func.FunctionApp()

    @app.route(route="HttpTrigger", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)
    def HttpTrigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
        logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
        resource = "499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default"
        endpoint = os.environ['IDENTITY_ENDPOINT']
        header = os.environ['IDENTITY_HEADER']
        headers = { 'X-Identity-Header': header }
        user_managed_identity_id = "&mi_res_id=my UMI resource ID"
        url = f"{endpoint}?api-version=2019-08-01&resource={resource}" + user_managed_identity_id
        name = req.params.get('name')

    if name == "choice1":
        resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        token = resp.json()
        token = token.get('access_token')
        azdevheaders = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {token}"
        }
        body = {
            "templateParameters": {}
        }
        uri = "https://dev.azure.com/<my org>/<my project>/_apis/pipelines/7/runs?api-version=7.0"
        cusname = req.params.get('cusname')
        r = requests.post(uri, headers=azdevheaders, data=body)

        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {cusname}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully, AzDo response code: {r}")
    
    elif name == "choice2":
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {cusname}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. {name}")
    
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )
```

Using Python I am making a request to get a bearer token for authentication, which works.
But when using the return bearer token to invoke a pipeline in Azure Devops, I get a 203 response, which pretty much returns the Azure DevOps sign in page and results in the Pipeline not being run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working correctly as expected by changing the following values.

```
resource = "499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default"
```

->

```
resource = "499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798"
```

and the following environment variables

```
endpoint = os.environ['IDENTITY_ENDPOINT'] -> ['MSI_ENDPOINT']
header = os.environ['IDENTITY_HEADER'] -> ['MSI_SECRET']
```

After making the required changes I was able to get a bearer token and authenticate against Azure Devops with a **Bearer Token**.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using below Azure Functions HTTP Trigger code with PAT token as authentication to run my Azure Functions code and it worked successfully like below:-

**init.py:-**

```py
import azure.functions as func
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    # Replace with your Azure DevOps organization URL
    organization_url = "https://dev.azure.com/organization"

    # Replace with your Personal Access Token
    personal_access_token = "mxxxxxoiakje75gxxxpjtzaqxxxxxq"

    # Replace with your project name and pipeline ID
    project_name = "AzureDevops"
    pipeline_id = 122

    # URL to trigger a new pipeline run
    api_url = f"{organization_url}/{project_name}/_apis/pipelines/{pipeline_id}/runs?api-version=7.1-preview"

    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }

    auth = HTTPBasicAuth("", personal_access_token)

    # Trigger a new pipeline run
    response = requests.post(api_url, json={}, headers=headers, auth=auth)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        return func.HttpResponse("Pipeline run triggered successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Failed to trigger the pipeline run. Status code: {response.status_code}, Error: {response.text}")
```

**Local Output:-**

[image]

[image]

***I deployed this Function in my Azure Function app and the pipeline ran successfully:-***

[image]

[image]

You can refer my [**SO thread answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76762959/i-want-to-add-tasks-to-multiple-azure-pipelines-i-created-a-script-to-install-t/76785105#76785105) where I have given code to create a pipeline and run the pipeline with Python.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with SPN and I am able to communicate with Azure DevOps API using the AD Token. I have added SPN as a user in the DevOps organization with Basic access and granted it permissions to the project.

```
import requests

# Azure AD details
tenant_id = '<tenant id>'
client_id = '<client id>'
client_secret = 'client secret'
scope = '499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default'

# Obtain an access token
token_url = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token'
token_data = {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'client_id': client_id,
    'client_secret': client_secret,
    'scope': scope
}
token_r = requests.post(token_url, data=token_data)
token = token_r.json().get("access_token")


# Call Azure DevOps API
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

# Example: Fetch list of projects in an Azure DevOps Organization
organization_name = '<organization name>'
api_url = f'https://dev.azure.com/{organization_name}/_apis/projects'

response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Other alternative would be 'HttpTrigger' as a function wrapping its logic.

```
import datetime
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import os
import requests
import json

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.route(route="HttpTrigger", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)
def HttpTrigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    resource = "499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default"
    endpoint = os.environ['IDENTITY_ENDPOINT']
    header = os.environ['IDENTITY_HEADER']
    headers = {'X-Identity-Header': header}
    user_managed_identity_id = "&mi_res_id=my UMI resource ID"
    url = f"{endpoint}?api-version=2019-08-01&resource={resource}" + user_managed_identity_id
    name = req.params.get('name')
    cusname = req.params.get('cusname')

    if name == "choice1":
        resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        if resp.status_code != 200:
            return func.HttpResponse(f"Error getting token, response code: {resp.status_code}", status_code=resp.status_code)
        token = resp.json().get('access_token')
        azdevheaders = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {token}"
        }
        body = {
            "templateParameters": {}
        }
        uri = "https://dev.azure.com/<my org>/<my project>/_apis/pipelines/7/runs?api-version=7.0"
        r = requests.post(uri, headers=azdevheaders, json=body)

        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {cusname}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully, AzDo response code: {r}")

    elif name == "choice2":
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {cusname}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. {name}")

    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
            status_code=200
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this same problem, I had to grant my Application Registration the "User Impersonation" scope for "Azure DevOps" (done in Entra ID under "API Permissions", on the App Registration itself).

One that was done, I had to modify the scope i was requesting from the OAuth endpoints to be:
`{GUID}/.default`

Where {GUID} was the value of the "Resource App ID" for "User Impersonation" for "Azure DevOps". Which you can retrieve by clicking on the newly granted permission in the Azure Portal.